# Laravel Undefined variable: store error but my store is defined

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to pass multiple parameters from my blade.php

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug, $product->uuid], 
'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

and it gives me the error:

> Undefined variable: store (View:/directory/products/variants.blade.php)

This is my Create in my controller:

```
    public function create($store, $id)
{
    $store = Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
    $products = $store->products()->findOrFail($id);
    return view('devoptions.products.variants', compact('store, products'));
}
```

what should I do? what is the correct way of passing multiple parameters?

EDIT: here is my whole variants.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin-default')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            {!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug, $product->uuid], 
            'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Add Variant</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Variants</h2>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="name">Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="slug" name="slug"> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <br>
                    <label for="retail_price">Retail Price</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="price_currency" name="price_currency" value="PHP"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="retail_price" name="retail_price"> 
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <br>
                <label for="acquisition_price">Acquisition Price</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="acquisition_price" name="acquisition_price">                                     
            </div>                                
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Product
            </button>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Show us your blade file `variants.blade.php`

Comment: @kgbph I have edited my question and added my variants blade.

Comment: It should be `compact('store', 'products')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

incorrect syntax compact()

```
return view('devoptions.products.variants', compact('store', 'products'));
```

Comment: Thank you HAHAHA that was a silly mistake. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`{!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['developer.variants.store', $store->slug, $products->uuid], 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}`

Comment: What's the difference between your code & the code in question??

Comment: you are get $products variable but you use $product, ' s ' missing.

Comment: return view('devoptions.products.variants', compact('store', 'products')); this also change your controller.